# Parse : How to perform a method when query's completed

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I'm saving an image along other objects using saveInBackgroundWithBlock: but then not sure how to get its instantly created objectId.

I can get the saved image file for another class I'm trying to send it to but I'm not exactly doing it right because I wait until user taps on something instead of sending it using delegate method right after saveInBackgroundWithBlock: is completed because I don't know how.

1. I need to get objectId of the object I'm saving.
2. Also need to know when it's saved in Parse so I can perform a method right away.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the call back to validate against in order to determine a successful save:

```
...saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
     if (success) {
       //this is how you know your object is saved and where you can potentially perform an additional query to retrieve it's objectId
     } else {
       //not successful 
     }
}
```

If you want to retrieve the object you just saved you'll have to perform a query to get its objectId. There is no right way to do this and there is no wrong way to do this. It's all about what works for you and your project.